# skipping copying contents of sub directories using rsync

Tags: rsync

```
rsync -avzm -e ssh /path/to/src/folder/ /path/to/dest/folder 
 --include=*/ --include=*/config.xml --exclude=*
```

I need to copy files(say config.xml) that are in the 2nd level directories using rsync. I am currently using  the above script and its copying config.xml's from all directory levels.

What changes should I make in the above command?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
rsync -avzm -e ssh -f'- /*/*/' -f'+ config.xml' \
    /path/to/src/folder/ /path/to/dest/folder
```

**Explanation**

- `-f` causes `rsync` to enable filter rule.
- `- /*/*/`:

  - `-` meaning exclude rule.
  - `/*/*/` exlucde any subdirectory from `3rd` level.
- `+ config.xml`: `+` meaning include rule, cause rsync copy all files that have `config.xml` in filename.

**Example**

```
$ ls -R dir1/
dir1/:
dir2  dir22

dir1/dir2:
config.xml.2  dir3

dir1/dir2/dir3:
config.xml

dir1/dir22:
config.xml.22  dir33

dir1/dir22/dir33:
config.xml

$ rsync -r -f'- /*/*/' -f'+ config.xml' dir1/ /tmp

$ ls -R /tmp/dir2*
/tmp/dir2:
config.xml.2

/tmp/dir22:
config.xml.22
```